# xcodeのストーリーボードからiPadのViewが消えた

Tags: swift, xcode

xcodeでアプリの開発を行っています。
Main.storyboard(base)から、いつのタイミングからかiPadが無くなりました。
iPadのViewは復元できるのでしょうか。

xcodeのバージョンは14.1です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Xcode 14.3ですがiPadも右側に出ていますね。
シミュレーター実行はiPad選べますか？

Answer (score 1):

Xcode14.3ですが、おそらく`Destination`にiPadが追加されていないからだと思います。

Xcode上でProjectファイルを開き、

`General` > `Supported Destinations`　> `Destination`

を参照しiPadが追加されているかどうか確認してみてください。

もし、追加されていなければ追加して、再度ビルドするとStoryboardに追加されていると思います。

以下の画像は、追加されている状態のProjectファイルとStoryboardです。

[image: DestinationにiPadを追加された状態]
[image: 追加された状態のStoryboard]